# count and get attribute of anchor tags of ckeditor's selected text

Tags: ckeditor

I want to get the selected text's anchor tags count and html eg. From Date  + To Date where From Date and To Date are anchor tags. Their source is as follows:-

```
<p>
    <a class="fic.fields" fieldognlexpression="${IUWP1_ICP_DT?string(datePattern)}" href="">
        From Date
    </a>
    &nbsp; +&nbsp;
    <a class="fic.fields" fieldognlexpression="${IUWP1_EXP_DT?string(datePattern)}" href="">
        To Date
    </a>
</p>
```

When i select `(From Date  + To Date)`, I want to get the number of anchor tags and the `fieldognlexpression` attribute of anchor tags i.e.
 `${IUWP1_ICP_DT?string(datePattern)} + ${IUWP1_EXP_DT?string(datePattern)}` as output in ckeditor only

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery here is how to do this.

```
var anchors = $('a');  // get all anchors by simple 'a' selector
var anchorCount = anchors.length;  // get anchors count
var expressions = []; // initialise empty expressions array

anchors.each(function(index){
    // loop through all anchors and add their fieldognlexpression attribute value to the array
    expressions[index] = $(this).attr('fieldognlexpression');
});
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Jcnkg/

Comment: I want it in ckeditor.I m not able to read the number of anchor tags in the expression.Neither i m able to get the expression from the source part of ckeditor

Comment: Unfortunately your requirements are very unclear, have a look at the ckeditor documentation as you can get and set the textEditor contents via javascript.  Also depending on the CMS you are using, the jQuery included may be incompatiblity mode and you therefore need to change all the `$` symbols which are part of the jQuery code above to `jQuery` i.e. `var anchors = jQuery('a');`